# Bootstrap 4 collapse

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

can anybody help me here make the collapse accordion work... Can't make it work, the code has some sense to me and it's equal to this one https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example.

I have a data-parent that is the .card itself with ID="companies", each collapse aims to this and each button to its respective collapsible content
It's for freecodecamp project. I have already made some web pages but the accordion never works for me, instead of hitting someone with a hammer. I believe it's better to ask the community

```
https://codepen.io/adrianwix/pen/rvNgxy?editors=1010

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1 class="text-center mt-4">Elon Musk</h1>
      <p class="text-center">A Quest for saving human race</p>
    </div>    
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h2>Who is he? Well...</h2>
      <blockquote>"If some of the things that Musk says and does sound absurd, that’s because on one level they very much are. On this occasion, for example, Musk’s assistant had just handed him some cookies-and-cream ice cream with sprinkles on top, and he then talked earnestly about <strong>saving humanity</strong>  while a blotch of the dessert hung from his lower lip."</blockquote>
      <p>Elon Reeve Musk (born June 28, 1971) is a South African-born American entrepreneur and businessman who founded X.com in 1999 (which later became PayPal), SpaceX in 2002 and Tesla Motors in 2003. Musk became a multimillionaire in his late 20s when he sold his start-up company, Zip2, to a division of Compaq Computers. </p>
    </div>
  </div> <!--ROW END-->
  <div class="row-">
    <div class="col">
      <h2>Musk's Companies</h2>
      <p>He is not only the owner of many companies, but all of them are focus on making human race evolve</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div> <!--ROW END-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div id="companies" class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <button class="btn btn-link" 
                      data-toggle="collapse" 
                      data-target=".spacex" 
                      aria-expanded="true" 
                      aria-controls="SpaceX">
                SpaceX
              </button>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" 
                      data-toggle="collapse" 
                      data-target=".tesla" 
                      aria-expanded="true" 
                      aria-controls="Tesla">
                Tesla
              </button>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" 
                      data-toggle="collapse" 
                      data-target=".solar" 
                      aria-expanded="true" 
                      aria-controls="Solar City">
                Solar City
              </button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div> <!--CARD-HEADER END-->

        <div class="card-body collapse show p-1 spacex" 
             id="spacex"
             data-parent="#companies">
          <img class="card-img img-fluid"
             src="https://icdn6.digitaltrends.com/image/digitaltrends_es/1-52-1500x1000.jpg" 
             alt="SpaceX last and best rocket in the world. Falcon Heavy">
          <div class="box">
            <h3 class="card-title">SpaceX</h3>
            <p class="card-text">A company with one single red star in front of them, colonizing Mars.</p>
    <a href="http://www.spacex.com/" class="card-link">SpaceX website</a>
          </div>
        </div> <!--CARD BODY END-->

        <div class="card-body collapse p-1 tesla" 
             id="tesla" 
             data-parent="#companies">
          <img class="card-img img-fluid" 
 src="https://www.tesla.com/sites/default/files/images/software_update.jpg" 
               alt="Tesla model 3 car">
          <div class="box">
            <h3 class="card-title">Tesla</h3>
            <p class="card-text">Detroid best enemy. Chose to produce electric cards when everyone believe it was impossible.</p>
            <a href="https://www.tesla.com/?redirect=no" class="card-link">Tesla website</a>
          </div>
        </div> <!--CARD BODY END-->

        <div class="card-body collapse p-1 solar"
             id="solar"
             data-parent="#companies">
          <img class="card-img img-fluid" 
               src="https://www.tesla.com/sites/default/files/images/software_update.jpg" 
               alt="Tesla model 3 car">
          <div class="box">
            <h3 class="card-title">Solar City</h3>
            <p class="card-text">Exploring new way to use renovable energy in order to protect the earth.</p>
            <a href="https://www.tesla.com/solarpanels" class="card-link">Tesla website</a>
          </div>
        </div> <!--CARD BODY END-->

      </div> <!--CARD END-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*
  font-family: Montserrat
#companies  
  .card-body
    position: relative
    .box
      position: absolute
      top: 20%
      left: 5%
      width: 40%
      color: white
      background: black
      padding: 1rem
      border-radius: 10px
```

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind First time codepen mistake... Jquery wasn't first...